# Else keeps giving me invalid syntax in python

Tags: python-3.x

I have recently started learning python from codewars.
Today I was working with this problem but I kept getting an error.
This was the problem: https://www.codewars.com/kata/56747fd5cb988479af000028/train/python

And this is the code i wrote :

```
    def get_middle(s):
               if len(s) %2==0:
            x =int(len(s))/2-1
            x = int(x)
            y = int(len(s))/2
            y =int(y)
    return s[x]+s[y]
    else:

            d = int(len(s))//2
            d = int(d)
    return s[d]
```

Every time I try to run it I get the error that else is an invalid syntax.
I'm sorry for anything I might have done wrong while posting this question since this is the first time I have posted here XD.

This is the error I got

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "n.py", line 1, in <module>
    import get_middle
  File "/home/kebi/Desktop/get_middle.py", line 8
    else:
       ^
SyntaxError: invalid syntax
```

I tried converting "d" into an "int" but I didn't know what else to do.

I expect the output to give me the middle letter of the word or when the word length is even the 2 middle letters.

Comment: Perhaps check your indentation?

Comment: @DeveshKumarSingh I tried moving else a bit forward and back but it still gives me an error

Comment: Please post the exact error details here.

Comment: Python depends on this indentations, so it needs more than a bit, everything inside the method needs to be indented. Everything inside the if or else needs to be indented even further. Do little by little until you get it all in with no errors.

Comment: @Leito ok I ll be trying that

Comment: @SupratimHaldar Should i edit my post to contain them as a screenshot?

Comment: Yes you can edit the question, but copy and paste the the error details in another code block at the end. Don't put a screenshot.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Python is block-indented, i.e. the indenting forms logical blocks.

This should resolve the syntax errors:

```
def get_middle(s):
    if len(s) % 2 == 0:
        x = int(len(s)) / 2 - 1
        x = int(x)
        y = int(len(s)) / 2
        y = int(y)
        return s[x] + s[y]
    else:
        d = int(len(s)) // 2
        d = int(d)
        return s[d]
```

I also put spacing around the operators, for readability.

Comment: I think my terminal had some problems i tried in an online interpreter and this worked , thank you very much XD.

Comment: Great advice, readability matters! One more piece of advice for @Kebi, don't use single letter variable names, makes it harder to understand.

Comment: @Leito So instead of "d" in this case i should have used something like "middle_letter"?

Comment: But you expect and convert it to a number, maybe `middle_digit`. You don't want a varaible call middle_letter with a integer as it's value. But yeah, much better than `d`.